# Django LogoutView is not working. How to resolve this problem using classbased default function?

Tags: django, authentication, security, django-views, django-urls

I want to use django buildin LogoutView library but it is not working. When i use this, it shows "This page isn’t working"
The logout function should work and logout the user.
Below is the urls.py code.

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import TaskList, TaskDetail, TaskCreate, TaskUpdate, DeleteView, CustomLoginView, RegisterPage, TaskReorder
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='login'), name='logout'),
    path('register/', RegisterPage.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('', TaskList.as_view(), name='tasks'),
    path('task/<int:pk>/', TaskDetail.as_view(), name='task'),
    path('task-create/', TaskCreate.as_view(), name='task-create'),
    path('task-update/<int:pk>/', TaskUpdate.as_view(), name='task-update'),
    path('task-delete/<int:pk>/', DeleteView.as_view(), name='task-delete'),
    path('task-reorder/', TaskReorder.as_view(), name='task-reorder'),
]
```

Comment: How dou you *use* the logout function. I assume you have a template where the user can click to logout the user? Can you share that page?

Comment: In the home page, Only logout url is linked only and used in this way below: 
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a> {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a> {% endif %}
</div>

Comment: @mahmudhasan124: well you should not use an `<a href="...">`, since that will make a GET request, and the HTTP protocol specifies that GET request should be "safe": i.e. have no side-effects. Some browsers might for example visit all links and prefetch the result and thus accidently logging out the user. That is why since Django-5.0, you can not log out with a GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Logout in my projects as follows:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('logout', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'), ]
```

and in views.py

```
#app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth import logout

class LogoutView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('login')
```

I hope it was useful for you.

Comment: Please *don't*: a GET request should *not* have side-effects, this violates the HTTP protocol: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-safe-methods

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the view, the problem is how you make the *request*. Logging out is a *state-changing* request, you should *not* do that with a GET request, since that violates the HTTP protocol. Therefore, since [django-5.0](/questions/tagged/django-5.0), it has to be done through a POST request, with a mini-form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">logout</button>
</form>
```